# Inaccurate Closest Waypoint Identification Near Line Intersections

Tags: javascript, turfjs

###### Issue I'm facing

The current method for finding the closest waypoint may not accurately determine the true nearest waypoint when the selected point is near the intersection of multiple lines. This is because the function relies **solely on the distance** between the clicked point and the waypoints' coordinates, **without** considering the lineStrings associated with each waypoint.

I'm open to suggestions for alternative approaches, such as using a spatial index or a different algorithm.

[image]

###### My current approach for finding the closest waypoint to a clicked point

I'm using Turf.js to draw lineStrings between specific points. I have an array of waypoints and I'm currently searching for the closest waypoint to a clicked point by comparing the clicked coordinates to the coordinates of each waypoint. I'm converting the clicked coordinates to a point on the lineString using the `turf.pointOnLine()` function and then finding the closest waypoint using the `findClosestWaypoint()` function.

###### Searching for the closest waypoint

```js
const findClosestWaypoint = (clickedCoordinates) => {
  let closestWaypoint = null;
  let minDistance = Infinity;

  waypoints.forEach((waypoint) => {
    const distance = turf.distance(
      turf.point([waypoint.longitude, waypoint.latitude]),
      turf.point(clickedCoordinates)
    );

    if (distance < minDistance) {
      minDistance = distance;
      closestWaypoint = waypoint;
    }
  });

  return closestWaypoint;
};
```

###### Usage of the closest waypoint later

```js
const clickedLineStringPoint = turf.pointOnLine(lineStrings, [coordinates.lng, coordinates.lat]);
const clickedCoordinates = clickedLineStringPoint.geometry.coordinates;
const closestWaypoint = findClosestWaypoint(clickedCoordinates);
```

Comment: Seems like you need to make use of https://turfjs.org/docs/#lineIntersect to introduce intermediate waypoints into your list of waypoints, no?  Otherwise, in your example, the intersecting line segments are simply considered a flyover interchange, and hence #1 and #2 are considered the closest waypoints rather than #1 and #4...

Comment: Yes, I've already tried using lineIntersect in my specific case, and it yielded positive results. Appreciate the suggestion!

Comment: So by positive results, does that mean you're closer to a solution or did that solve the problem posed by your question?